# GNU find on MacOS

Tags: macos, find

I've downloaded the GNU version of `find` with homebrew:

```
brew install findutils --with-default-names
```

When I run `which` on `find` I get what I expect:

```
$ which find
/usr/local/bin/find
```

However, when I use `find`, the system falls back to OS X default `/usr/bin/find`, i.e.:

```
$ find -exec file {} \;
find: illegal option -- e
usage: find [-H | -L | -P] [-EXdsx] [-f path] path ... [expression]
       find [-H | -L | -P] [-EXdsx] -f path [path ...] [expression]

$ /usr/local/bin/find -exec file {} \;
.: directory
```

Why is this happening and how can I get `find` to work properly?

Comment: check your $PATH. probably the osx default one is in a dir that appears EARLIER in your $PATH than the gnu version. e.g. `path=/bin;/usr/local/bin`, if you have find in both, then it'll run the `/bin` version first

Comment: @MarcB but shouldn't `which` return `/usr/bin/find` in this case? I just checked my $PATH and `...:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:`, so the default isn't earlier.

Comment: Brew installed GNU find is accessed by adding a "g" in front of `find`. `gfind`. `which gfind
/usr/local/bin/gfind`
`which find
/usr/bin/find`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Just start a new terminal. A system restart is an overkill.

Answer (score 27):

EDIT SEP 2023: See @Ambareesh's comment below this; my answer is now obsolete (as are many of the earlier answers).

If you still have an this problem, I would just reinstall brew from scratch using defaults (or there may be an easier way).

---

`brew` has changed since this question was posted. The accepted answer was not correct before - not enough for someone to follow anyways (rebooting wasn't the answer) - but *now* the packaging of `brew` and pathing has also changed.  To keep this page relevant, here is the new answer.

This shows MacOS provided find, which defaults in the system $PATH:

```
$ which find
/usr/bin/find
```

This installs GNU find:

```
$ brew install findutils
```

While it has been installed, it does not touch the mac version, nor will it assume the default in your path. This is to prevent surprises. You could stop here and do no additional configuration, but to target the GNU version your scripts would need to specify the full path to the executable.

Now, make GNU default (first in path), meaning just a plain `find` command invokes it, you will need to put the GNU find's directory "first" in your path. In my case manage $PATH in `$HOME/.bash_profile` but on some systems that could be `$HOME/.bashrc`.

```
PATH=$(brew --prefix)/opt/findutils/libexec/gnubin:$PATH
```

^^ You might have other things already "ahead" of your default PATH var. You can either add this verbatim as a new line, or carefully insert the string (including the `$` and using the `:` to separate from the next value)

In every shell window open, reload your env:

```
$ source ~/.bash_profile
```

Or, close all your terminal windows. New terminal windows will have the updated PATH var. DO NOT reboot.

Now check your `find`:

```
$ which find
/usr/local/opt/findutils/libexec/gnubin/find
```

Hooray, GNU is the default `find`. But we did not harm the OS default find -- it is still there, so any macOS-specific scripts will still find it:

```
$ ls /usr/bin/find
/usr/bin/find
```

If you come across any non-Apple, macOS scripts that heavily *assumed* "find" is of the BSD type (Apple's version), but you installed GNU find first in your search path, then you will run into a compatibility problem with Brew. Because BSD 'find' has options that GNU 'find' does not, and vice-versa. Few scripts assume you use BSD find, but if you encounter this: Just add a line to the top of that script to alias `find` to the correct one, or you can manipulate `$PATH` so that `find` goes to the correct installed instance of the command, or if none of this sounds easy you can edit the script so that all instances of `find` command include the fully-qualified-path to the correct version. But need for this paragraph is rare. :-)

**Be aware that `--with-default-names` functionality is *removed*** (yet, confusingly, the brew website still *suggests* this option). With any modern Brew install, trying to use `--with-default-names` will just give you an error message. Things change, and unfortunately the Brew website is always seriously outdated for reasons not made clear,

Comment: As of 2023, brew post-installation message says `All commands have been installed with the prefix "g"` so you can access it like `gfind`.

Answer (score 6):

Note that the `--with-default-names` has been [removed](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/commit/8c4f31e6643469493fc26d275be09cb05b09beac). Now one has to explicitly add the binary to the path, as instructed when installing.

Answer (score 3):

I don't like changing the OS -- I don't know but some other utility might depend on the find command that comes with the OS which may cause issues down the road. So what I do is create an alias in .bashrc.  So do the brew install findutils, that will put a /usr/local/bin/gfind, in your .bashrc put alias find='/usr/local/bin/gfind'  Every time you type find, it will use gfind from /usr/local/bin/gfind.  All you need to do to activate is to source .bashrc. or just start a new terminal. No need to reboot. I do this with a lot of the gnu utilities and makes it easy to undo, just remove the alias.

Answer (score 0):

Bash caches the paths. Use `hash -r` to clear it.
See https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-hash

Answer (score -6):

The solution couldn't be any easier:

A simple system restart.

Comment: You don't need to do a system restart. It's installed, so he just needs to refresh his PATH variable. He can do `source ~/.bash_profile`

Comment: Nothing was added to the PATH. See the comments to the question. Besides, your solution implies I‘m using Bash, which I‘m not.

Comment: Which shell are you using?  There may be an equivalent command for your shell. Did you check the PATH from a new instance of the terminal, or one that was open before you ran the `brew install` command?

Comment: "Which shell" is an irrelevant distraction. With ANY shell, "reboot" is not the correct answer.  This question is a highly ranked one in Google, and lots of OSX users want to give the GNU version of `find` precedence over the Apple-provided BSD version.  If those visitors view this accepted answer, it will not help them.

Comment:   Found the Windows sysadmin.